# Join two array with same index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem about how to joining two arrays like this?

```
var arrayA = [a,b,c,d,e]
var arrayB = [1,2,3,4,5]

result : [ [a,1], [b,2], [c,3], [d,4], [e,5] ]
```

(In angularjs)

Comment: What's the actual problem? SO is not for "how do I ....", that's what google is for. What have you found that will let you do this, and how did that not work for you?

Comment: what did you try ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try below

```
var arrayA = [a,b,c,d,e], 
    arrayB = [1,2,3,4,5]
var output = arrayA.map(function(value, index){
  return [ value, arrayB[index]]
})
console.log(output);
```

OR you could go for library such as [**underscore.js**](http://underscorejs.org/).

Comment: @artemist : Do mark the answer correct if it solves your problem. Really helps the next guy looking for a solution.

Comment: i do, it's need 2 minutes for marking it after comment. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not using angular just Js

```
var arrayA = [a,b,c,d,e];
var arrayB = [1,2,3,4,5];

var result=[]; 

for(i=0;i<arrayB.length;i++){
     result.push([arrayA[i],arrayB[i]]);
}
```